# Want to go to next image when button is clicked but the app keeps crashing

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var ind1 = 0;
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  var im1:ImageView=findViewById(R.id.im1) as ImageView
  var im2:ImageView=findViewById(R.id.im2) as ImageView
    b1.setOnClickListener()
    {
        if (ind1 == 0) {
        im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.int1)
        im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1)
        } 
        else if (ind1 == 1) { 
            im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.int2)
            im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2)
            welcome.text=""
            scroll.text = "-=--"
            data.text = "Generate Random Teams To Make It More Interesting!"
        } 
        else if (ind1 == 2) {
            im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.int3)
            im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3)

            scroll.text = "--=-"
            data.text = "Choose From Knockouts,Leagues Or Hybrid Tournaments!"
        } else if (ind1 == 3) {
            im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.int4)
            im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.i4)

            scroll.text = "---="
            data.text = "Have Fun And Enjoy!!"
            b1.text = "LETS GO"

        }
        ind1++


    }
}
```

}

also tried making an intarrayof and putting the values into that but the app still keeps crashing without giving any error also without the imageviews changing the app works perfectly fine

Comment: provide stacktrace, also - what is ind1?

Comment: What error do you receive? Why it is crashing?

Comment: the app just crashes without giving any error installs perfectly

Comment: yet after the crash you surely have a stacktrace in logcat.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hCQnjsCk

Comment: The log says _"java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(432000000bytes) bitmap."_ and that's why the app crashes. That's over 400 MegaBytes which is quite much for a mobile device to handle as a bitmap.

Comment: That is enough. :) And large bitmaps are a common problem. Some image loader/viewer libraries like Glide, Picasso, SubSampledImageViewer etc. are sometimes useful as they have some memory management already implemented.